# Vice and Vice President

Tags: etymology, idioms, vocabulary

The word "vice" is usually used in a negative sense in the meaning of "immoral or wicked behavior". On the other hand we have a commonly used term "vice president" as the second person in a presidency system. As a non-native speaker when I first saw "vice president" I thought that it was something like "king of parties and all kind of entertainments" :). Obviously no one else understands it in this way.

What is the relation between the word "vice" and the term "vice president"?

Comment: I once read about A vice president in charge of vice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The negative "vice" has its roots here:

Middle English, from Old French, from Latin **vitium** *fault, blemish, crime, vice*

while

the prefix "vice-" has its roots in the Latin
**vice**    *in place of*

[Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary]